# Is there a light weight workflow orchestration library available

Tags: .net, software-design

**Our Requirements:**

- A light-weight .NET library that lets us define operations and then define a workflow using these operations.
- Workflow should be definable in code.
- Some operations could be declarable as concurrently runnable.
- A UI to define the workflow is fine, however not nececssary.

**Don't need**

- This is not for long-running business workflows, rather relatively short, for modularizing 'generic operations' in our code. So, don't need to save state.
- We don't want a 'server' component, just a library, we can integrate.

Am I talking about a 'workflow' or is there a different name for my requirement?

Comment: You should ask this on: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Business workflow is the concretization of a state machine abstraction. Have a look to different "state machine" libraries which may be used in your application. For example, [Stateless 3.0 - A State Machine library for .NET Core](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Stateless30AStateMachineLibraryForNETCore.aspx)